# dynamic data in drop down in salesforce from other site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, visualforce

I have a drop down in a visualforce page . The data needs to populated from a rails app that i have developed.So how should i populated the options from the rails site into my visualforce page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is

1. Return XML from RoR url
2. Add external site to salesforce instance (Setup | Security Controls | Remote Site Setting)
3. Use `HttpRequest` / `HttpResponse` to ask for and receive xml from RoR.
4. Use XML DOM support to parse and extract info (see [example](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Spring10/XML+DOM+Parsing))